Why am I getting seq scan with RLS but not with equivalent query? Hierarchical data, filtering on user + relatives
I'm working with an architecture where users have hierarchical relationships. User100 could have a parent of User50 and a grandparent of User1. User100 would need to be able to see records owned by itself and it's parent/grandparent.
I want to use an RLS policy to accomplish this but it seems to be much less efficient than a comparable query.
I have table1 which includes a user_id field, denoting ownership of records. I would like to use an RLS SELECT policy to filter records so that for the current_setting('current_user'), records are only retrieved that are owned by the user or their parents/grandparents. I have another table called relatives_table that I need to query to obtain the user_ids that should be visible for a current_user.
When I do a SELECT * query on table1 with RLS enabled, I get a sequential scan. But when I do a SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE , I get a much more performant query that uses an index on table1.user_id.
I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, where does my misunderstanding lie, or is this an issue with Postgres15 RLS?
Here's the RLS policy:
CREATE POLICY table1_select_policy ON table1
FOR SELECT USING (
user_id IN (
SELECT related_user_id
FROM relatives_table
WHERE user_id = current_setting('current_user'), TRUE)::ksuid
)
);

I have a btree index on user_id in table1. And yet...
When I SELECT * FROM table1; with the RLS enabled, I get a sequential scan:
"Seq Scan on table1  (cost=8.62..6910.96 rows=67654 width=375) (actual time=0.124..43.863 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (hashed SubPlan 1)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 135387"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Index Scan using related_user_id_idx on relatives_table  (cost=0.43..8.61 rows=5 width=28) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=4 loops=1)"
"          Index Cond: ((user_id)::bpchar = ((current_setting('app.current_user'::text, true))::ksuid)::bpchar)"
"Planning Time: 1.412 ms"
"Execution Time: 43.920 ms"

Now, when I disable RLS and perform the equivalent query, it is much more efficient and uses the index:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT related_user_id
    FROM relatives_table
    WHERE user_id = current_setting('current_user', TRUE)::ksuid
);

"Nested Loop  (cost=4.77..316.01 rows=3 width=375) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.47..4.48 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: (relatives_table.related_user_id)::bpchar"
"        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB"
"        ->  Index Scan using related_user_id_idx on relatives_table  (cost=0.43..4.47 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((user_id)::bpchar = ((current_setting('current_user'::text, true))::ksuid)::bpchar)"
"  ->  Index Scan using table1_user_id_idx on table1  (cost=0.29..267.88 rows=4365 width=375) (never executed)"
"        Index Cond: ((user_id)::bpchar = (relatives_table.related_user_id)::bpchar)"
"Planning Time: 0.603 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.069 ms"

There's about 135,000 records in table1 and about 42,000 records in the relatives_table.
